# Cron Job Redirect Stdout/Stderr to Log File and Mail Only Stderr

Tags: cron, stdout, stderr, mailto

As the title suggests, I'd like my cron job to redirect STDOUT to a log file, and mail only the STDERR output. If you have an idea of how to approach this or point me to some prior art, that would be very helpful.

For more context, I am creating backups of a github enterprise server using github's backup utility tools. The cron job executes a shell script and [according to their documentation](https://github.com/github/backup-utils/blob/master/docs/scheduling-backups.md#example-scheduling-usage), it redirects STDOUT to a log file and generates an email with STDERR output. However, based on my understanding it's redirecting both STDOUT and STDERR to the log file. Their example cron:

```
MAILTO=admin@example.com

0 * * * * /opt/backup-utils/bin/ghe-backup -v 1>>/opt/backup-utils/backup.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux stderr is file descriptor 2 ; what you really want to do is specify another filename for stderr as shown below

```
0 * * * * /opt/backup-utils/bin/ghe-backup -v 1>>/opt/backup-utils/backup.log 2>/opt/backup-utils/backup_stderr.log
```

Comment: But wouldn't that just write the error log to a file without generating an email?

Comment: I am not aware of the script so cannot really comment. Are you not able to tweak the script to meet your requirements ?